# Show session list in view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, razor

I'm learning ASP.NET MVC and I have some problem to understand and use `session` the right way. Let me explain what I have done and what I want to achieve.

First I create a session with a list of Products in the Index method of the Home controller. I also add some default products into the list like this:

```
Session["ShoppingCart"] = new List<Products>() { new Products { ID = 1 }, new Products { ID = 2 } };
```

(My goal is to use this session later in other controllers to be able to add products, but for now I just want to do some testing.)

Then in the Shop controller I have an action method to show the content of the shopping cart. This is where I start to get lost in this wonderful world.

The thing that I can't solve is how I should treat the Session["ShoppingCart"] so that I can view the list of products that are in the list!? Should I have a view with an IEnumerable to be able to iterate it the list with razor?

Comment: Just as a note, be careful for using sessions for data that is important to keep around. I have to deal with an ecommerce solution that uses sessions for carts, and it's a huge source of customer frustration as their carts just disappear, seemingly to them as random. In truth, sessions are temporary and transient, and if you're not using a persistent backing like SQL Server, even more so. With in proc sessions, they are destroyed any time the app pool even recycles. I'd recommend saving the "cart" to a database, tied to their user account, so the user doesn't ever lose it.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3):

you can code in view like this

```
List<Products> list = (List<Products>)Session["ShoppingCart"];


@foreach(var item in list) 
{
        do what ever 
}
```

i hope i works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I get a red line below the word list and the error message is: The name list does not exist in the current context. Do I have to add something more in the beginning of the file?

Comment: Seriously? You need to import the System.Collections.Generic assembly.

Comment: `using System.Collections.Generic;`. You should just be able to right-click and resolve.

Comment: Right idea, but don't do it this way; use `as`, e.g. `Session["ShoppingCart"] as List<Product>`. The former will throw an exception if it can't be casted, while `as` will merely set the variable to null. You can then use a conditional to check for null and proceed accordingly.

Comment: I guess there has been some miss understanding here! The line of code with: List<Products> list = ..... should be in the controller, right!? And using System.Collections.Generic; is already there. I was wondering about the View and I got the red line there in the Razor for each loop and I still have. What have I missed?

Comment: Well, you can technically add using statements in your view as well, but `List` should not need one in a Razor view.

Comment: OK, so then I don't know what is wrong and why I get the red line!? :(

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like the code given below

```
var list = Session["ShoppingCart"] as List<Products>;
```

I prefer to use the as keyword since there is no 100% guarantee that the Session will contain the list (due to application pool refresh, website being restarted, etc). Gives you that extra bit of defence to avoid a NullReferenceException.

Then do your process

```
if (list != null){
   foreach(var item in list) 
   {
       your custom code
   }
}
```

hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

In this case the best you can do is to define a Shopping Cart class:

```
public class Cart{
    IList<Products> Products {get; set;}
    // any other properties that you would need or structure this in way to store quantities, prices per line and so on
}
```

Then and assuming that you don't have any problem storing that in session, you just access it like (and please note you always need to cast anything you get from Session):

```
var cart = (Cart) Session["ShoppingCart"];
// do any work you need on the cart object
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but do I really need to use a Cart class? Why can't I just add Products to a list?

Comment: You can do, but it's cleaner and easier to encapsulate the content. Anyway apply the same logic but instead of casting it to Cart, just cast it to your List<Products> if you don't want to use the wrapper class.

Comment: OK, but I don't understand all of your answer. var cart = ..... is this in the view and should I use @ sign before the var cart = .... and how can I loop the list of Products? It was that I needed some help with.

Comment: Yes, that can be in the view or the controller. The syntax was for controller, for the view is will depend what viewengine you are using.     @{ var cart = (Cart) Session["ShoppingCart"];
} assuming that you're using Razor. Iteration and all that has nothing to do with the original question. Just search how to iterate a c# List.